# Tool Identity and Use

Tags: hand-tools, saw, identify-a-tool

I'm hoping someone can identify this hand tool.
Here is what I do know:

- It was made by Stanley
- It may be something used with sheet metal or maybe Wire?
- It would only be used on the edge of the metal.
- It doesn't seem to be used to nibble as it doesn't cut.
- The knob on the front has numbers from 4 to 16 (gauge?) and acts like a cam. as you turn it, it moves a metal piece (a base) that has two sloped edges with a peak in the middle. This piece adjusts up and down to offset the peak.
- There is another round wheel that you can turn to adjust the height of another component that has a rounded top edge.
- Squeezing the handle pushes a metal part that presses against the sloped adjustable base.
  It seems like it crimps or pinches? or possibly is used to bend. the part that is pushed is about 1/8" x 3/8" and the tip is sloped at the same angle as the metal plate it hits against.

[image: Full pic]
[image: close up head]
[image: close up angle]
[image: close up head 2]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It appears that you have a Stanley™ Saw Blade Set tool. It's possibly the model 42SS as per an [eBay posting](https://www.ebay.com/itm/304809436132?hash=item46f80ee3e4:g:KQIAAOSw%7EGhj8C4r) currently active.

[image: Saw blade set tool 42SS]

This image from above linked auction/purchase posting. There are other images in the linked site from various angles.

Saw blade setting tools are used to bend alternating teeth on a hand saw or circular saw blade to ensure suitable kerf/clearance while cutting

Answer (score 9):

It's a *saw set*, used for setting the teeth of a saw blade when resharpening.  See [saw set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saw_set).

Comment: Maybe worth to point out that the linked Wikipedia page actually shows a picture of exactly that tool as an example for two-handled or pistol-grip saw sets: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Stanley_42W_saw_set.jpg#/media/File:Stanley_42W_saw_set.jpg.